# visual studio release management 2013 "Copy File or Folder" does not work with build variable

Tags: ms-release-management

"Copy file or Folder" action give the "Invalid path" error when there is a build variable in either source or destination file path. 
E.g "D:\TfsDeployments\$(BuildNumber)". It's working fine for static path.

Does anyone know how the variable can be used in file path for copy purpose?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Variables only work with components, not with actions. This is because you can use Release Management without tying a release template to a particular build definition. What would `$(BuildNumber)` if there was no related build?